# Illegal Start of Expression on Calculator using Ternary Operators

Tags: java

I have a homework where I need to make a basic Java calculator. The problem is that it needs to use ternary operators, and I can't find a way for my code to compile, I always get an error here or there. Currently I have 4 errors, which is the least I've gotten until now, but now I can't figure out a way to make it work, I have tried everything I can think of, but it still doesn't work. I was wondering if you could please check it out.

```
class PpalCal
{
    char operacion;

    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        Calculadora Cal;
        Cal=new Calculadora();
        Cal.v1=Float.parseFloat(arg[0]);
        Cal.v2=Float.parseFloat(arg[1]);
        Cal.op=Character.parseCharacter(arg[2]);
        {
            String operacion = (Cal.op = +) ? "suma" : 
            (Cal.op = -) ? "resta" : 
            (Cal.op = *) ? "multiplicacion" : "division";
            if (operacion.equals("suma"))
            {
                System.out.println("La suma es :"+Cal.sumar());
            }
            else
            {
                if (operacion.equals("resta"))
                {
                    System.out.println("La resta es :"+Cal.restar());
                }
                else
                {
                    if (operacion.equals("multiplicacion"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("La multiplicacion es :"+Cal.multiplicar());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("La division es :"+Cal.dividir());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error telling me that there is an illegal start of expression on lines 13, and 14 with the closing parenthesis of (Cal.op = +) and (Cal.op = >-), and two errors telling me the same on line 15, but now with the asterisk >as well on (Cal.op = *).

Comment: are you sure there is a method `Character.parseCharacter`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

equality testing is a double `==` and the chars need to be enclosed in single quotes so:

```
Cal.op == '+'
```

Comment: Alright, thanks, but now I get an error saying "Cannot find symbol" and it marks the second period on line 11 Cal.op=Character.parseCharacter(arg[2]);

Comment: You can just write `Cal.op = arg[2].charAt(0)` I guess. @JorgePietraSanta

Comment: `Character.parseCharacter` - never seen this method.

Comment: @Sweeper That fixed it, now I have one last problem, the code is supposed to make a multiplication when I use '*' but when I try to run the code, it just ignores the asterisk and skips straight to the division. Any help with that?

Comment: @Sweeper Nevermind I got it, thank you both for all your help, I really don't think I could've pulled this out without your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Statements(Ternary Statement) require boolean as output to identify true or false condition.So in your case

```
            String operacion = (Cal.op == '+') ? "suma" : (Cal.op == '-') ? "resta":(Cal.op == '*') ? "multiplicacion" : "division";
```

Answer (score 0):

A ternary operator needs condition statement that return true or false state.
So you need to, use ==  to compare it with  a char enclose it with single quotes.

```
Cal.op == '+'
```